# How can a packet reach another EC2 instance in another subnet without any router in between?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing

The question is regarding routing inside VPC subnets. I know, VPC internally handles any routing between it's internal subnets. But, how can a MTR packet (ICMP) reach another subnet without any router?

```
$ mtr -rwn -c 2 10.1.2.145
Start: 2020-03-06T06:19:10+0000
HOST: ip-10-1-1-172.ec2.internal Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 10.1.2.145                  0.0%     2    1.6   4.1   1.6   6.6   3.6
```

Instance1 route table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

Instance2 route table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

ICMP works just like TCP / UDP, it's routed inside your VPC by the "virtual router" (AWS Hyperplane). The AWS route table has a default route that all subnets can communicate with each other. If you want to change that you change the route table associated with the subnet.

Comment: From the AWS docs, it seems like, Hyperplane is used for specific AWS services like NAT gateway, NLB etc. and AWS uses VPC encapsulation and mapping service for routing packets between its instances. You mentioned about changing the default behavior by altering routing table, so is there any way to route traffics between subnets in a VPC through a router or another instance? (Though AWS docs, says the local route responsible for routing inside VPC is kind of immutable or unchangeable.)

Comment: Don't worry about Hyperplane, but if you're interested watch the Re:Invent video. I can't recall off the top of my head if you can alter the default route, I've never needed to, typically I would use a NACL or Security Group to restrict things. I don't really subnet any more without good reason, I usuall tier with security groups.

Comment: I've already watched the re:Invent video. Yeah, I know inter-subnet communication can be controlled by NACL or Securiy Group, I was just interested about the inner concepts of routing inside VPC. Adding my findings in the answer section, so that it may help others who have the similar question in mind.

Comment: So can I say aws vpc uses hyperplane（virtual router） for inter-VPC or intra-VPC communicating with the help of mapping service（sdn controller）?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, got the answer of my own question. AWS uses VPC encapsulation to route traffics between instances. The VPC encapsulation contain info about destination VPC and ENI id. In AWS, a physical host may host multiple instances from different customers and different VPCs, so there is a chance that a single host may contain instances of different VPCs (from different customers) with same CIDR. To avoid this kind of ambiguity AWS stamps their environment specific information by adding this encapsulation. There is also a contribution of the Mapping service. Which contains the info about which ENI in a VPC resides in which physical host. So, routing of the packets between instances is managed differently than the traditional IP based routing and unsurprisingly underlying IP layer of the physical network is not visible by the virtual instances.

References:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gc2DgBqo9U
2. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/understanding-amazon-vpc-from-a-vmware-nsx-engineers-perspective/

Comment: You didn't ask about inter-VPC routing, you asked about subnet routing, if you had I'd have mentioned the encapsulation :) Basically - AWS has a network that routes packets, it doesn't _really_ matter all that much how it does it, what matters is the configuration and controls that a user can apply.

Comment: Yes, I didn't ask about inter-VPC routing and my answer wasn't for inter-VPC specific too :). The references I've shared haven't differentiated between inter-VPC or intra-VPC communication, to discuss about VPC encapsulation. From 2nd refernence:"All packets are encapsulated using VPC encapsulation at the virtualization layer. The VPC encapsulation carries additional information like source and destination ENIs and VPC ID to the encapsulated packet."